# Include SoundCloud music in my app

Tags: java, android, api, soundcloud

This is the Java code:

```
final String songs_url[]={
    "http://soundcloud.com/qassim/brbjjajwsfcz"
};

btn_play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(songs_url[0]);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } // might take long! (for buffering, etc)
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
});
```

But when I run the emulator the sound does not start. I Googled the problem and found links from SoundCloud that started with http://www.api.soundcloud.com....
This API links when include it in Java sounds are played.
What is the problem

1. What is SoundCloud API?
2. How I get my tracks with links started with API?

Answer (score 1):

All SoundCloud resources are accessed and manipulated in a similar way. A list of the latest resource is usually available through /[resource name], a single specific resource through /[resource name][id] and related subresources like a tracks comments through /[resource name]/[id]/[subresource name].

Resources are returned as XML by default, or JSON if a .json extension is appended to the resource URI. We encourage you to use JSON. You can also send an appropriate Accept header specifying the format you would like. For example, a request with the header Accept: application/json will return resources represented as a JSON document.

Are you making this Emulator in eclipse? if not what program are you making the Emulator in.

This link is a guide to embedding soundcloud into programs: 
http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs#uploading

What is SoundCloud API? :
http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference

I've read that a lot of people don't suggest using it directly, but instead using something like a Java-API-Wrapper. Try using this link to learn how to use the Java-API-Wrapper. I'm not quite sure how to use it, therefore I can't walk you through it.

https://github.com/soundcloud/java-api-wrapper